# Google fit data not retrieved with python

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-fit

I created a service account in Google API to retrieve fit data.

If I try in the API playground it works fine (I could see the different data sources available)

If I try with the following code:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'api-project-248165331787-5a2b3821f120.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
fit = googleapiclient.discovery.build('fitness', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

response = fit.users().dataSources().list(userId='me').execute()

print(response)
```

I get an empty list as response. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: A service account is not you a service account is a dummy user. If service accounts do work with Google fit you would only be accessing the data owned by the service account.  How would a service account have submitted any data?   API playground uses Oauth2 not service accounts.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you have a link on how to use python with Oauth2? I was able to only find links for interactive applications, but I need to use a script to get the data

Comment: Not with that api but the drive example might give you a few tips https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that is searching a way to use python from a script to access fit data:

Go to google api console: [https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=\](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=%5C)<your project> :

- click on "Create Credentials" -> OAuthClientId -> Application Type -> Desktop App
- Download json credentials
- run the following script:

```
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read']

def main():
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_console()
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    fit = build('fitness', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    response = fit.users().dataSources().list(userId='me').execute()
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The script prompts an url, put that in the browser and write back the returned code in the script input.

Thanks @DalmTo for the tips provided

Comment: I understand this code uses OAuth process to return the access token, would the fitness API access also work with service accounts?

Comment: I was not able to find a way to use a service account